# Возможность позволить пользователю настраивать компоновку (java)

Tags: java

Хочется позволить юзеру настраивать компоновку элементов на экране. Для примера приведу eclipse IDE:

Здесь можно растягивать и переставлять компоненты:

[image: image1]

Менять перспективы:

[image: image2]

Добавлять и убирать панели:

[image: image3]

И делать ещё кучу всякого всего. 
Вот и вопрос. С реализацией всего этого париться самостоятельно или существуют какие-то классы, библиотеки? Просто не в первый раз вижу, не только здесь, и реализовано везде примерно одинаково. Неужели нигде нет ничего на эту тему?

Comment: а зачем? каждый сам решает как ему удобно работать. Зачем тогда всех заставлять работать под одним видом IDE?

Comment: Вы, вероятно, не до конца поняли вопрос. Дело, как раз, в том, чтобы позволить пользователю настраивать окно практически полностью. EIDE я привёл для примера, как это может быть реализовано. Но делать такое вручную со всеми наворотами - дело затратное.

Comment: для каждого IDE - свои настройки. например, Intellij IDEA хранит настройки. позволяет их экспортировать и импортироавть в новом месте, чтобы их не настраивать заного. Универсального решения, насколько я знаю, не существует.